# Is it safe to install grub to /dev/sda?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, 15.04

I have Windows 10 and I want to install Ubuntu. I want to be able to make GRUB (eventually BURG) my default boot loader for Windows 10 on `/dev/sda4` and Ubuntu on `/dev/sda7`. Should I install GRUB to `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sda7` and just use `F12` key on boot?

For Windows, I use Windows Bootloader (an EFI on `/dev/sda2`).

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI or BIOS boot mode. If Ubuntu is in UEFI boot mode, grub adds an ubuntu folder into the existing ESP - efi system partition that you have for Windows. MBR is not used with UEFI. And if UEFI burg will not work. If you want a graphical boot loader with UEFI look at rEFInd. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing different things. There is a little bit of code in the MBR. The MBR is right at the beginning of your HDD and also stores other stuff like the partition table. However, the information which can be stored there is not enough to boot a modern computer, and the format of MBR doesn't allow for storing any more data there. The classical generic MBR only provides 446 Byte for this and the modern standard MBR even only 218 Byte. (There are others as well.)

This code then loads information from a partition. If you use grub, the information is loaded from a Linux partition, namely from `[whatever partition]/boot/grub` and takes up 6.9 MB on my machine. The code Windows puts into the MBR also needs to load more information information from a partition. It's a lot more information and Windows gives it its own partition. That's why you have a partition about 100 MB in size when your computer came with Windows.

So you need to install the bootloader to `/dev/sda`. The installation process then will take care of putting the data it can't store in the MBR into `[whatever partition]/boot/grub`. Don't install the bootloader to a partition.